# Fancybox image gallery with ratings and comments

Tags: php, jquery

I have a photo website which gathers images from a folder with PHP, displays their thumbnails on a page and, when clicked, opens a fancybox (fancybox.net) to display the full image. I am pretty satisfied with the result but as users start posting, they start asking for new features, and problems come out since I'm not a programmer. 
 What I would like to do is a photo commenting/rating system (like the one on facebook to get the idea, but obviously not as complex): I've been trying to add a Disqus code to each picture, but it won't get displayed in my fancyboxes...So the question is, can you give me any (easy-to-implement) ideas on how to achieve this? I don't mind using already existing softwares like disqus for comments and polldaddy for ratings, since I guess it would require me to setup a mysql database to do it on my own...

To brief it again:
I have a "thumbs" folder which are gathered on a page.
I have an "originals" folder with the full size images that are called back by the fancybox.
I would like to have comments+rating in the fancybox.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give me.

Comment: Do you got have a database in background?

Answer (score 0):

For your fancybox implementation I'm assuming that it's just pulling the image into the lightbox, not other content (i.e. a html page). What you'd need to do is set up a page which would grab an image, and output it along with your comments + rating code, then set up your script to use that page as the fancybox URL instead of a direct link to the image.

Without more information to go on I can't really help more than that.

ps for comments the [Facebook Comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) might be easier for a non programmer to implement than Disqus.

Comment: Just after posting my question I've done what you just told me, in a slightly different manner: each thumbnail links to a img.php file, which gets the image filename like this img.php?name=*** Now I've embedded the facebook commenting system into the page, and it loads fine, but when I change picture and the fancybox reloads the comments go away and don't show anymore...